# Oracle SQL return the 1st difference

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data table

[image: Source Data]

And would like to produce the result table with SQL in Oracle as:

[image]

I tried using "LAG" and it is not working as I expected.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The query should return the date and value which is not equal to the current value for past dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lateral join might be the simplest solution:

```
select t.*,
       t2.date as lastchangedate,
       t2.value as lastvalue
from t left join lateral
     (select t2.*
      from t t2
      where t2.date < t.date and
            t2.value <> t.value
      order by t2.date desc
      fetch first row only
     ) t2
     on 1=1;
```

An alternative approach uses window functions.  One method is to use `lag()` to determine when the value changes and then to spread this through the group of rows:

```
select t.*,
       last_value(case when prev_value <> value then prev_value end ignore nulls) over (order by date)
from (select t.*,
             lag(value) over (order by date) as prev_value
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d1a9995c941379db998eb9595fba4ebe) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: And `fetch first 1 rows only` in correlated subquery

Comment: Lateral join works perfect. However, my real table t contains millions of rows, the performance is slow.  Is there any other way having better performance?  Thanks.

Comment: @gordon-linoff... Thanks.  I tried using Lag as the way you described, the result is not quite correct.  It shifted one row.

Comment: `code` SELECT tmp.vdate,
       tmp.value,
       lag(CASE
              WHEN prev_value <> VALUE THEN
               prev_date
           END ignore NULLS) over(ORDER BY vdate) AS PrevDate,
       lag(CASE
              WHEN prev_value <> VALUE THEN
               prev_value
           END ignore NULLS) over(ORDER BY vdate) AS PrevValue
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               lag(VALUE) over(ORDER BY vdate) AS prev_value,
               lag(vdate) over(ORDER BY vdate) AS prev_date
          FROM myData t) tmp
 ORDER BY vdate DESC; `/code`

Comment: @yxw158 . . . Ah, yes.  The subtle difference between `last_value()` and `lag()` in this case.  I included a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Closing parenthesis omitted in `over (order by date` in second SQL.